# DNS: Have a domain on one server and the files on another

Tags: dns, resolve

I have two domains (www.example1.com, www.example2.com).
Main domain is www.example1.com and the files are on the same server as where the domainname is hosted.

The client now has registred a new domain (www.example2.com) at some other hosting company.
What he wants is to use www.example2.com to show the webcontent that is located at the same server where www.example1.com is hosted.

So what I did is the following:
- www.example2.com DNS directed the A-record 'www' to the server where the files are.
- I waited the DNS-resolvement out and now the domain resolves to the server but on a default page that tells the user that there is nothing here.
  This is good because now the server is responding but just doesn't know where to send the user to.
- I added an alias www.example2.com and didn't redirect it.

This should work but obvious doesn't otherwise I wouldn't be asking a question here.

So can anybody tell me what I'm missing here?

M.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure the web server to accept the requests from the new domain name. Currently that site must only be accepting requests from the first domain name. You don't say what OS the web server is running, so it is difficult to be more precise but somewhere you will need to add a new alias for that site.